# How to switch user from the gnome-shell status menu

Tags: gnome

In gnome-shell 3.18, the"User" part of the status menu only allows to close the session, not to switch to another user, preventing the system from having several users logged in at the same time. Previous versions of gnome-shell and the current version of Unity (in Ubuntu 16.04) have this capability.

How can I recover this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

This was a [bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1577049) in Ubuntu 16.04. The bug fix is in the accountsservice package and will be automatically applied when you install updates for your computer.

*Edited*: My original answer gave a workaround for this bug.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks, but for some reason, locking the session doesn't work in my setup, I must haved messed something up.

Comment: Do you know whether you are using lightdm or gdm3?

Comment: Actually, switching to gdm also restored the "switch user" option ! I had to install ubuntu-gnome-desktop for gdm to work though, some of its dependencies must have been needed.